# Bash String substitution with '*' (asterisk) in String

Tags: bash

I have a query string (stored in `$QUERY_DISCREPANCIES`) such as:

```
SELECT (field_a * 100) / 2
FROM ...
```

I am attempting to add the executed query into an email that I send out. The email template contains a row with `<QUERY>`. However when I use String substitution as follows:

```
email=${email/<QUERY>/${QUERY_DISCREPANCIES}
```

then my HTML output is similar to:

```
my_file.sh query_test.sql templates test 100),2)
```

Seems that when substituting the `*` character, it's not properly escaping it.

Not sure if I can continue to use string substitution, or if I have to resort to something more sophisticated.
Help appreciated, my attempts using sed were not very successful.

Comment: How are you later using the variable `$email`? Seems like you are missing double quotes around some expansion :)

Comment: @PesaThe Oh wow! That worked! I just pass $email into a function that runs mutt to send an email. I just echoed `"$email"` and it is not escaping anything. Thanks so much

Comment: @mmenschig Try running your script through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- there are a bunch of gotchas like this, and it's pretty good at spotting the common ones.